# java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1,527 with message Connection refused (Connection refused)

Tags: apache2, java, ufw, database

I'm running into problems with the use of Apache Derby with IntelliJ's Ultimate edition.

When creating the **Data Source and Drivers**, after filling the form, I test the connection and I get the following error:

**java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1,527 with message Connection refused (Connection refused).**

[image: apacheDerbyConnection]

I have enabled the ufw and also allowed the connections from port 1527, which is, the main port the Apache Derby uses.

[image: ufw]

I have also checked the connection:

[image: ping]

Though I still cannot create the connection...

What should I do ?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the the output of `netstat -tlnp | grep 1527`

Comment: After running the command > netstat -tlnp | grep 1527 < I get nothing  @vidarlo

Comment: So derby isn't listening on port 1527.

Comment: How to do that ? @vidarlo

Comment: I have no idea. I've never touched derby, but a starting point would be to verify that it's configured correctly and listening on the port you anticipate.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of terminal output - [edit] your question to paste the actual text from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

> After running the command > netstat -tlnp | grep 1527 < I get nothing

You get nothing because nothing is listening on port 1527. That's also why you get connection refused; there is nothing that is ready to accept packets on that port.

This is not a firewall issue. The issue is simply that derby isn't running, or isn't running on port 1527.

Comment: I run > systemctl restart * < but I don't know the app name so cannot check if the status is activated @vidarlo

Comment: How did you install and configure Apache Derby?

Comment: I have downloaded the software from: **https://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/install_software.html**

Comment: This page >https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.13/adminguide/tadminappssettingportnumb.html< tells the Apache Derby default port which is 1527

Comment: @DBG I'd suggest you ask a new question where you *detail* the steps you have performed, and ask why Derby is not listening. Don't link to the tutorial, show us the running config. You may delete this one if you like, or edit it to be about why derby is not listening.

Comment: The askubuntu's server has banned me from asking other questions...